# angular chart not populating with data from API response

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-chart

i'm facing a challenge ploting  ChartJs bar chart in my angular app  with the data coming from my api response

this is the code snippets

```
<div class="canvas">
  <canvas id="canvas" baseChart [data]="barChartData" [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend" [type]="'bar'">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

```
this.barChartData = new Chart('canvas', {
      type:"bar",
      data:  {
        labels: ["Private", "NASHA", "NHIS", "Others"],
        datasets:[{
            data: [ 
              this.apiResponse?.Private,
              this.apiResponse?.data_1
            
            ],
           
            label: 'hey',
            backgroundColor: [ '#E8E2F4']
             
        
        }]
      },
      options:{
        scales: {
          y:{
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }
      }
      
    })
```

now the issue is that the chart is not pupolating and when i console the api response befor creating the chart i get the values as expected, but when i console the value after the chart, it returns undefined

pls what can be the cause, and how do i fix it

Comment: Can you provide the API response to the question? Thanks.

Comment: The API response are 6 &15

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038701/2358409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `apiResponse` is the response from the API, you should subscribe to the observable and assign the response value to `apiResponse`.

My concern based on your current code is as you are using the NG2-Charts directive, you are not correctly passing the value to those inputs such as `[data]`, `[options]`.

**Solution 1: With NG2-Charts**

The `barChartData` should be the `ChartData<'bar'>` type but not `ChartConfiguration<'bar'>`.

```
barChartData!: ChartData<'bar'>;
barChartOptions!: ChartOptions<'bar'>;
barChartPlugins!: any;
barChartLegend = true;

this.barChartOptions = {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
  },
};

of({
  Private: 6,
  data_1: 15,
}) /* Replace this with the observable that you call the API */
  .subscribe((resp) => {
    this.apiResponse = resp;

    this.barChartData = {
      labels: ['Private', 'NASHA', 'NHIS', 'Others'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [this.apiResponse?.Private, this.apiResponse?.data_1],
          label: 'hey',
          backgroundColor: ['#E8E2F4'],
        },
      ],
    };
  });
```

**Solution 2: Pure Chart.js**

For pure Chart.js, you can do as below:

```
of({
  Private: 6,
  data_1: 15,
}) /* Replace this with the observable that you call the API */
  .subscribe((resp) => {
    this.apiResponse = resp;

    new Chart('canvas2', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Private', 'NASHA', 'NHIS', 'Others'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [this.apiResponse?.Private, this.apiResponse?.data_1],
            label: 'hey',
            backgroundColor: ['#E8E2F4'],
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    } as ChartConfiguration<'bar'>);
  });
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-twqate?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: thank you, it worked but pls is it possible to have 2 background colors(1 color for the chart with the highest  value & the other color for the other charts

Comment: Provide different color codes in `backgroundColor`? [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-twqate?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: that is an option i have looked at, but the values are coming from API, so how do I know which bar will have the highest value so I can make the bg color different from the remaining bars?